# linux domain socket credentials : how to check two scheduled process have same cron ancestor

Tags: linux, process, cron, communication, credentials

Let's say i have some `scott` user.

In `scott`'s crontab, i have two tasks scheduled :

- **task1** is sort of "server" task which wraps some *information* and serve it through unix domain socket (task process will remains till a SIG_xxx ends it, whatever ...)
- **task2** is executed every day;every execution will need the *information* wrapped in **task1** memory. To achieve this, it will use unix domain socket in a client way.

I would like to ensure that an extra process (even if owned by `scott`) outside of `scott`'s cron "scope" (don't know how to express it really) won't be able to get the *information* from **task1** server.
Clearly i'd like **task1**'s *information* served only to the tasks scheduled in `scott`'s crontab.

Would the unix socket domain credentials mechanism be helpful to achieve such thing ?